# Regular expression for replacing `<del>` tag inside style and script tag blocks

Tags: regex

I want a help from you to strip `<del>` tag from `<script>` and `<style>` tags blocks e.g.

```
Input:

<style type="text/css">
   <del>p</del>
    {
    color:red;
     }
</style>
```

---

```
Output: 

<style type="text/css">
      p
      {
      color:red;
      }
</style>
```

same is for script tag too.. Basically I want to strip `<del>` tag from script tag and style tag block.

Comment: have you attempted anything yet?

Comment: yes i am using '/(?>(?><|\G)[^<>]++\K|\G(?<!^))<[^>]++>/' but its not stripping inside style and script tag

Comment: Why don't you use simple string replace method?

Answer (score 0):

using a `sed` command:

```
sed 's/<del>\(.*\)</del>/\1/g' yourFile.html
```

Comment: yes i l be using preg_replace but i want the regular expression for matching text inside script and style block specifically..

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
$text = '<style type="text/css"> <del>p</del> { color:red; } </style>';
$pattern = '/<\/?del>/g';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

**EDIT**

To specifically target occurrences inside a style tag:

```
$text = '<style type="text/css"> <del>p</del> { color:red; } </style>';
$pattern = '/(<(?:style|script).*)(<del>)(.*)(<\/del>)(.*<\/(?:style|script)>)/g'
$replacement = '$1$3$5';
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

There's probably a neater way of doing this without so many wildcards, but this gets the job done. I've not tested it in PHP but it works fine in JavaScript. You could do the same for style tags

Comment: sir it will replace the del tag everywhere but i want to remove this only inside script and style block

Comment: No problem - I updated it to match both style and script so check the latest edit. P.S. try to be more specific with your questions so that people have more of a chance to get them right first time!

Comment: sorry sir but this regex is not working in every case..                  `<script type="text/javascript">
 googletag.cmd.push(function() { <del>goo</del>gletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1379506098645-3'); });
 </script>`

Comment: It still works on the code you've pasted. Could it be PHP specific, or related to escaping strings? I notice you have a `'` and `"` in the same string and neither of them are escaped. P.S. if you find my answers or comments helpful, please upvote/accept. :)